# Pass on value from dependencies in include_router to routes FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I was wondering if it was possible to pass the results from the `dependencies` kwarg in `include_router` to the router that is passed to it. What I want to do is decode a JWT from the `x-token` header of a request and pass the decoded payload to the `books` routes.

I know that I could just write `authenticate_and_decode_JWT` as a dependency of each of the routes in routers/book.py, but this would be quite repetitive for a large app.

main.py

```py
from typing import Optional
from jose import jwt

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Header, HTTPException, status
from jose.exceptions import JWTError

from routers import books


app = FastAPI()

def authenticate_and_decode_JWT(x_token: str = Header(None)):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(x_token.split(' ')[1], 'secret key', algorithms=['HS256'])
        return payload # pass decoded user information from here to books.router routes somehow
    except JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

app.include_router(
    books.router,
    prefix="/books",
    dependencies=[Depends(authenticate_and_decode_JWT)], 
)

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

routers/books.py

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get('/')
def get_book():
    # do stuff with decoded authenticated user data from JWT payload here
    pass

@router.post('/')
def create_book():
    # do stuff with decoded authenticated user data from JWT payload here
    pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the answer above about writing a middleware does work, if you don't want a middleware, you just want to use the `include_router`, then you can take the `authenticate_and_decode_JWT` method and extend it to write the JWT payload into the `request` object and then later have your routes read from that out from the `request` object.

This way you only need to modify a few lines in your code for it to work:

```
from fastapi import Request  # <== new import

def authenticate_and_decode_JWT(x_token: str = Header(None), request: Request):   # <== request is a new param
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(x_token.split(' ')[1], 'secret key', algorithms=['HS256'])
        request.token_payload = payload  # type: ignore   # <== store the token payload in request
        return payload # pass decoded user information from here to books.router routes somehow
    except JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

And then read from `request`:

```
from fastapi import Request   # <== new import

@router.get('/', request: Request)   # <== request is a new param
def get_book():
    # do stuff with decoded authenticated user data from JWT payload here
    print(request.token_payload)   # <== access your token payload
```

Answer (score 11):

For the larger application you mentioned, You can do following things,

1. Write a Authentication Backend. So, you can access request.user from every route

```py
class BearerTokenAuthBackend(AuthenticationBackend):
    """
    This is a custom auth backend class which will allow you to authenticate your request and return auth and user as
    a tuple
    """
    async def authenticate(self, request):
        # This function is inherited from the base class and called by some other class
        if "Authorization" not in request.headers:
            return
        auth = request.headers["Authorization"]
        try:
            scheme, token = auth.split()
            if scheme.lower() != 'bearer':
                return
            decoded = jwt.decode(
                token,
                settings.JWT_SECRET,
                algorithms=[settings.JWT_ALGORITHM],
                options={"verify_aud": False},
            )
        except (ValueError, UnicodeDecodeError, JWTError) as exc:
            raise AuthenticationError('Invalid JWT Token.')
        username: str = decoded.get("sub")
        # QUERY FROM DATABASE/CACHE add to user
        user = None
        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationError('Invalid JWT Token.')
        return auth, user
```

2. Add the Middleware to application startup

```py
app.add_middleware(AuthenticationMiddleware, backend=BearerTokenAuthBackend())
```

3. You you can access `request.user`

```py
@router.get('/')
def get_book(request: Request):
    print(request.user)
    # do stuff with decoded authenticated user data from JWT payload here
    pass
```

**I've written this hack for myself. You can suit like yours.**

Comment: great information, as a new to FastAPI - could you please let me know, is there any document for creating custom middleware

Comment: You can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525132/how-to-write-a-custom-fastapi-middleware-class