# How to customize response messages for ReDoc OpenAPI documentation in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi, redoc

I have developed some FastAPI app, and want to customize its redoc documentation. Below is the code for it:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Optional

import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    username: str

user_list = ["John", "Abrahim", "Kiana"]

#Get method to fetch some value
@app.get('/user/{id}/')
def users(id:int):
    return user_list[id]

#Request Bodies
#Post Method
@app.post('/user')
def add_user(request:User):
    return request.username


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

As of now I am getting below response in my redoc documentation:
[image]

I want to add more response codes in redoc like below and also wants to customize the messages against each code. Not sure how to do, so please help in it.

```
200 - OK    Everything worked as expected.
400 - Bad Request   The request was unacceptable, often due to missing a required parameter.
401 - Unauthorized  No valid API key provided.
402 - Request Failed    The parameters were valid but the request failed.
403 - Forbidden The API key doesn't have permissions to perform the request.
404 - Not Found The requested resource doesn't exist.
409 - Conflict  The request conflicts with another request (perhaps due to using the same idempotent key).
429 - Too Many Requests Too many requests hit the API too quickly. We recommend an exponential backoff of your requests.
500, 502, 503, 504 - Server Errors  Something went wrong on Stripe's end. (These are rare.)
```

Comment: Start here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customise error response in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952692/how-to-customise-error-response-in-fastapi)

Comment: See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003764/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726285/17865804)

Comment: @Helen As I have to add multiple status codes and customize the response message, can you please help me with adding some code couplets to the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/#combine-predefined-responses-and-custom-ones):

> You might want to have some predefined responses that apply to many
> *path operations*, but you want to **combine them with custom responses** needed by each *path operation*.
>
> For those cases, you can use the Python technique of "unpacking" a
> `dict` with `**dict_to_unpack`:
>
> ```
> json old_dict = {
>     "old key": "old value",
>     "second old key": "second old value", 
> } 
> new_dict = {**old_dict, "new key": "new value"}
> ```
>
> Here, `new_dict` will contain all the key-value pairs from `old_dict` plus
> the new key-value pair:
>
> ```
> json {
>     "old key": "old value",
>     "second old key": "second old value",
>     "new key": "new value", 
> }
> ```
>
> You can use that technique to re-use some predefined responses in your
> *path operations* and combine them with additional custom ones.

### Working Example

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    value: str


responses = {
    404: {"description": "Item not found"},
    302: {"description": "The item was moved"},
    403: {"description": "Not enough privileges"},
}


app = FastAPI()


@app.get(
    "/items/{item_id}",
    response_model=Item,
    responses={**responses, 200: {"content": {"image/png": {}}}},
)
async def read_item(item_id: str, img: Union[bool, None] = None):
    if img:
        return FileResponse("image.png", media_type="image/png")
    else:
        return {"id": "foo", "value": "there goes my hero"}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, It helped me. I was able to modify the code as per my example. I may need some more help on this. I will put it that in separate question, if required.

Comment: I can find these modified responses in redoc but I ain't getting these modified responses in actual application. For example I can't override the 500 internal server error response.

Comment: Declaring additional `responses` to appear in the API docs doesn't mean the content of such responses/exceptions will be automatically changed to those you specified. As described in the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/#additional-responses-in-openapi), _"...for those additional responses you have to **make sure** you return a `Response` like `JSONResponse` directly, with **your status code and content**"_. Please have a look at the links provided in the comments section above, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804)

Comment: can we edit or remove the response samples pane coming in right side.