# How to change authenticated error message in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Can I change 'authenticated' error message in FastAPI?

For example, in my login section, the current error message is:

```
{

"detail": "Not authenticated"

}
```

and I want to change the error message

Comment: i use OAuth2PasswordBearer for authenticated (by depends) and automatically return the error and i want to customize it

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726285/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545471/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269047/17865804) helpful.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your help, the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved

`OAuth2PasswordBearer` class that automatically sends an error to the client when the token is not valid.

This class has an entry (`auto_error`) that we can give it when defining this class and avoid sending this error automatically

If this entry is filled, no error will be returned automatically and instead, None will be returned, and then we can send our own customized error code to the client.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Check out this pages: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#dependencies.

In your endpoint you can a parameter like: `token: Depends(check_authorization)`. Then write your own `check_authorization` method, where you return your own custom `HTTPException`. You can find nice examples about that here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#handling-errors

Comment: i use OAuth2PasswordBearer for authenticated (by depends) and automatically return the error and i want to customize it

Comment: I think this will help you: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#oauth2passwordrequestform.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem is solved

Comment: Great! You're welcome