# fastapi: use middleware to generate a result in which the original result is included as an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, middleware, fastapi-middleware

there is this code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    # execute the request
    results = await call_next(request)

    return JSONResponse(content={
        'response': results 
    })

  
@app.post("/test/")
async def test_func():
    results = {
        'test': 10
    }

    return results
```

but errors are generated

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type 
_StreamingResponse is not JSON serializable
```

how to correctly pass `results` as an output dictionary element

Is `JSONRespons`e necessary at all?

I thought it could be done simply:

```
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    # execute request
    results = await call_next(request)

    return {
        'response': results 
    }
```

but no

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) answer your question? Related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883126/17865804) as well

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882419/fastapi-how-to-get-the-response-body-in-middleware