# Using Dependency Injection to get class instance in functions that are not routes

Tags: python, fastapi

There is a class called `MsvConfig` in which I want to keep some app configurations. I want to load this class using Dependency Injection. One of settings I keep in config is `CORS_origins`.

```py
def create_app() -> FastAPI:

    app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(MsvConfig)])
    app.include_router(features.product_search.endpoints.endpoints.router)

    return app

app = create_app()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event(msv_config: MsvConfig = Depends(MsvConfig)):

    origins = msv_config.CORS_origins

    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )
```

When I try to do it this way, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'CORS_origins'

Can you give me a hint how it should be solved? Every example of using `Depends` shows it on a FastAPI's http endpoints, but here I need to do something before any request arrives to my API.

Comment: If you want to execute some code before entering your route it's not a depends you need but a middleware (typically what you use for authentication)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525132/how-to-write-a-custom-fastapi-middleware-class
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/

Comment: but I do use middleware. My code exaple is adding CORSMiddleware at startup

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, not really getting expected results from trying to hook up DI in FastAPI.  I would expect the framework to instantiate the classes that are being passed in with `Depends` so that they can be used as if someone constructed the object with it.  On top of it, should have some place where you can configure per injected object if it's singleton or instance and framework manages single/multiple objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use dependency injections in this case. Simply importing the class will suffice. Dependency injection in FastAPI is indented for reading data that is modified with every request.

Python does not double import modules that have already been imported.